# SQL Server: Insert a new row for every unique value in column 1

Tags: sql-server, insert, sql-update, insert-into

Using SQL Server I am trying to find every unique value in column 1 of a table, and then insert a new row using that unique column 1 value and adding a column 2 value.  Column 2 value will be the same every time.

To note: I could do this by pulling out the unique values from the database on column 1 and adding an insert for each but I have 1.6 million unique values in column 1 so it would be tiresome to write it that way.

Taking 2 unique value from column 1 to show this as an example:

```
select *
from dbo.SettopSubscription
where MacAddr = '0000000ee4b5'
   or MacAddr = '0000003a9667'
```

Results:

```
MacAddr      PackageId   
------------ ----------- 
0000000ee4b5    11
0000000ee4b5     3
0000003a9667   241
0000003a9667   241
0000003a9667    11
0000003a9667   211
0000003a9667     8
0000003a9667  4411
0000003a9667  4412
0000003a9667  4479
```

Now I want to add PackageId = 37 to every unique MacAddr value but so far no luck in writing something to find and add on only the unique values.  As stated before I can do this easily by writing an insert into script for each MacAddr but that was take forever on 1.6 million MacAddr values.

Beginning view, same as above:

```
MacAddr      PackageId   
------------ ----------- 
0000000ee4b5    11
0000000ee4b5     3
0000003a9667   241
0000003a9667   241
0000003a9667    11
0000003a9667   211
0000003a9667     8
0000003a9667  4411
0000003a9667  4412
0000003a9667  4479
```

End result:

```
MacAddr      PackageId   
------------ ----------- 
0000000ee4b5    11
0000000ee4b5     3
***0000000ee4b5    37***
0000003a9667   241
0000003a9667   241
0000003a9667    11
0000003a9667   211
0000003a9667     8
0000003a9667  4411
0000003a9667  4412
0000003a9667  4479
***0000003a9667    37***
```

Thanks for the help ahead of time.

Comment: *Now I want to add PackageId = 37 to every unique MacAddr*  Do you want this to be part of filter or what ?

Comment: So just to clarify, you want to select distinct `column1` from `table1` and insert that value back into `table1` with various values in `column2`? Or do you want values from `column1` that only occur once so far, and insert those back into `table1` with values in `column2`?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by a filter, I am newer to mssql but in other scripting I would most likely add the unique MacAddr values to a list then run a for or if statement to add new rows for every value of MacAddr in that list.  Is that possible in mssql?

Comment: So when you find a unique value in column 1, you want to update column 2 of that value or you want to insert a row with that value and a value of column 2?

Comment: It might be of some help to give us a sample of what your table looks like initially, and a sample of the data that you want it to look like at the end. That should clear up any confusion.

Comment: gmiley I would want the first instance of your question.  Find the distinct/unique values in column1 and then add a new value for column2 using that distinct column1 value

Comment: Well distinct and unique are different things, that is why I asked for clarification. You seem to use them interchangeably. Providing sample before and after datasets should help in clearing that up.

Comment: Amazigh.Ca. the latter.

Comment: I have edited to show a beginning and end result to the table for those 2 MacAddr values in column1, end result is to add a new row for each dinstinct/unique MacAddr with a value in column2 of '37'.

Comment: but I see the value 0000000ee4b5    from your first select is not unique, you have tow

Comment: My fault on that Amazigh.Ca, couldnt edit it again fast enough before you caught it.  It is now updated.

Comment: So it looks like you just want to add another entry for each distinct `MacAddr` to create a new record with a `PackageId` of `37`? One for each `MacAddr`. I assume you also do not want to insert a duplicate if a record already exists for `PackageId` = `37`?

Comment: you are correct gmiley.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will insert a record for each distinct `MacAddr` with a `PackageId` of `37` that does not already have a `PackageId` of `37`:

```
insert into SettopSubscription (MacAddr, PackageId)
select distinct s1.MacAddr, 37 
from SettopSubscription s1
where not exists
(
    select s2.PackageId
    from SettopSubscription s2
    where s2.MacAddr = s1.MacAddr
    and s2.PackageId = 37
);
```

Comment: This works as intended and adds the addition of not writing a duplicate row if PackageId = 'x' already exists.

Answer (score 2):

To `INSERT` a new record into the `SettopSubscription` table for each unique value of `MacAddr`, with a `PackageId` of `37` (not inserting if there is already a record in the table for that combination of `MacAddr` and `PackageId`:

```
INSERT INTO SettopSubscription (MacAddr, PackageId)
SELECT DISTINCT s1.MacAddr, 37 
FROM dbo.SettopSubscription s1
LEFT JOIN dbo.SettopSubscription s2 ON s1.MacAddr = s2.MacAddr 
                                   AND s2.PackageId = 37
WHERE s2.MacAddr IS NULL
```

Comment: This looks pretty close to what he was asking for, but I think I would put a condition on there to exclude any `MacAddr` that already has a `PackageId` of `37` - at least according to the confirmation in the comments.

Comment: Works as intended, thank you!  trying the other options to stop the possibility of writing duplicate rows.

Comment: Anyone have a solution to add to this that would eliminate the addition of the new row if PackageId = 37 was already in the table?

Comment: @Tim see my answer, if 3N1GM4 updates his soon I will remove mine.

Comment: Yep, this will work too. If OP wants to accept yours as the answer since you mostly had it first, I am fine with that. Will upvote yours either way. =)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
insert into dbo.SettopSubscription (MacAddr,PackageId)   
select MacAddr, 'your_PackageId_Value'  from 
(select count(dbo.SettopSubscription.MacAddr ) nbr, MacAddr  from
dbo.SettopSubscription group by MacAddr ) tmp where tmp.nbr=1
```

Comment: This will run but not add the new value to the table.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want this:

```
declare @pid int
set @pid=37
insert into dbo.SettopSubscription (macaddr, packageid)
select distinct ss.macaddr, @pid
from dbo.SettopSubscription ss
where not exists (
    select * from dbo.SettopSubscription ss2 
    where ss2.macaddr=ss.macaddr and ss2.packageid=@pid)
```

For every unique macaddr in column 1, this is just inserting a record with the packageid you indicated and making sure the combination does not yet exist.

I added the variable under the assumption you might reuse the query. Putting a literal 37 in multiple locations can easily lead to data issues if on a future run, you only update the first use of the literal.

Comment: Server: Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Line 3: Incorrect syntax near ','.