# SQL Server: Insert from second table for every unique value in first table with matching condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-insert

I have a first table of customer data:

```
|BillTo |ShipTo_Code|Name    |Address           |ProductNum |UoM |Price  |
|:------|-----------|--------|------------------|-----------|----|-------|
|101308 |0526       |Store 1 |118 Washington St.|           |    |       |
|101308 |0542       |Store 2 |62 Central St.    |           |    |       |
|101308 |0716       |Store 3 |15 Walnut Rd.     |           |    |       |
|101308 |0817       |Store 4 |211 Sudbury Rd.   |           |    |       |
```

And I have a second table that has product and pricing data for customers:

```
|BillTo |ProductNum |UoM |Price  |
|:------|-----------|----|-------|
|101308 |3100121    |CS  |2.90   |
|101308 |3100697    |CS  |2.45   |
|101308 |3300072    |CS  |67.80  |
|101308 |3300075    |CS  |5.45   |
```

I need to insert the pricing data into the customer table so that all 4 products appear for every change in ShipTo_Code. It should end up like this:

```
|BillTo |ShipTo_Code|Name    |Address           |ProductNum |UoM |Price  |
|:------|-----------|--------|------------------|-----------|----|-------|
|101308 |0526       |Store 1 |118 Washington St.|3100121    |CS  |2.90   |
|101308 |0526       |Store 1 |118 Washington St.|3100697    |CS  |2.45   |
|101308 |0526       |Store 1 |118 Washington St.|3300072    |CS  |67.80  |
|101308 |0526       |Store 1 |118 Washington St.|3300075    |CS  |5.45   |
|101308 |0542       |Store 2 |62 Central St.    |3100121    |CS  |2.90   |
|101308 |0542       |Store 2 |62 Central St.    |3100697    |CS  |2.45   |
|101308 |0542       |Store 2 |62 Central St.    |3300072    |CS  |67.80  |
|101308 |0542       |Store 2 |62 Central St.    |3300075    |CS  |5.45   |
|101308 |0716       |Store 3 |15 Walnut Rd.     |3100121    |CS  |2.90   |
|101308 |0716       |Store 3 |15 Walnut Rd.     |3100697    |CS  |2.45   |
|101308 |0716       |Store 3 |15 Walnut Rd.     |3300072    |CS  |67.80  |
|101308 |0716       |Store 3 |15 Walnut Rd.     |3300075    |CS  |5.45   |
etc.
```

The only match between the 2 tables is the BillTo.

I've spent a lot of time looking at similar questions here, but have not really been able to apply the solutions I've seen in threads so far.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268176) gave me a good start, but it's doing it within the same table.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Why 817 is not in the expected output? What is logic?

Comment: Sorry, I left that out when making the table. 817 would be represented, as well.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a `join`:

```
select c.*, st.*
from customers c join
     secondtable st
     on c.billto = st.billto
order by c.shipto_code, st.productnum;
```

Comment: this is close, but not quite. When I run this, I get all of the columns for both tables and all of the data in separate rows. I tried adapting this into an INSERT query:  
  

    `INSERT INTO Customers (ProductNum, UoM, Price)  
    SELECT (ProductNum, UoM, Price)  
    FROM Price st JOIN Customers c  
    ON c.BillTo = st.BillTo  
    ORDER BY c.ShipTo, st.ProductNum'`  
    

  and that inserted into the right columns, but put everything in new rows.

Comment: @adgy . . . Just select the columns that you want.